# Does the business layer keep working even a session closed in the middle of process?

Tags: .net, session

What happens if the user closes their browser while a called business service method is still processing?

Does it keep executing without knowing that the user has closed their browser or does the process suddenly stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will continue to process and return the response when it's done. If the browser is closed the response is simply dropped when it is received by the clients PC.

Comment: Wouldn't it crash when it writes to a closed stream?

Comment: Not immediately i don't think. The stream would either time out or 'buffer out' - ie. it might throw an exception when the buffer was empty and it was expecting another 'continue' request from the client. Not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

The server is not aware of the actions of the browser. So your business layer will keep on processing.